# It will be delivered after it [ is | was | will be ] inspected?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, future-tense

I have a problem understanding the difference between these sentences. Before new chapter in my English book I was kind of ok with all three sentences, but now I'm having trouble understanding them and if any is incorrect too.

Three sentences are:

> - a/ It will be delivered after it is inspected.
> - b/ It will be delivered after it was inspected.
> - c/ It will be delivered after it will be inspected.

Could you tell me if there is any difference between them and what that is?

1. I feel that a/ and c/ are very similar in meaning and both correct but I b/ feels kinda wrong/weird to me but I don't know why or if that is actually true.
2. What is the difference between a/ and c/ (and b/)?
   Thank you very much for help.

Comment: As a native speaker, sentence (a) is the only one that seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connective prepositions *before, after, when, while, as soon as*, etc.  may be added to a clause to express that a second activity occurs *earlier than, later than or at the same time* as the activity in the main clause.

If the verb in the main clause is present tense, the verb in clause following the preposition is also present.

> After we finish our homework, we go for a walk. (later then, as we
>   usually do)

Connective prepositions may also be added to a clause with a future tense verb expression such as *will* or *(be) going to*. In this case, the verb in the clause *following the connective preposition* does not change tense. It remains in present tense form.

> After *we finish* our homework, *we'll go* for a walk. (later then, today)

So, the correct choice will be

> It will be delivered after it is inspected. (first it will be inspected then delivered)

The difference between variants A, B, and C is that only variant A is grammatically correct.

Comment: Indeed, the correct choice is that. :)

Comment: Thank you. So although both actions happen in the future because of use of 'after' I have to say it in present tense. Does the same apply if I say it in reverse order? For example: 'It will be inspected and then delivered' or can I say 'It will be inspected and then it will be delivered'?

Comment: @VicoLemp - Absolutely. In that case a comma is needed: After it is inspected, it will be delivered. As for the two examples, either will work.