# Harmonization of two simple sentences in the future tense

Tags: sentence-construction, future-tense

I want to say in one phrase:

1. We'll be back.
2. Then rain will start.

To my oppinion this should be like:

> We'll be back before the rain will start.

According to the google translator:

> We'll be back before the rain starts.

Which of us is more right? Why?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116258/it-will-be-delivered-after-it-is-was-will-be-inspected

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate is correct in this case.

In English, when we're referring to a future event in relation to something else, we normally use the present tense.  Think of it this way: right now, we say the rain *will start*, because it is in the future.  That is, it *will* start even if we're talking about right now.  So it doesn't make sense to say you will be back before it *will* start, because it already was and has been true that it *will start*.  What you mean is that you will be back before the actual event of it starting - that is, when *it starts*.