# Future perfect in a time clause

Tags: grammar, future-tense

I’ve read the sentence “After I’ll have finished eating my lunch by 2 p.m, I’ll go to the supermarket” and I’m confused because the rules say we should always use a present tense in a time clause but “I’ll have finished” is a future tense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It will be delivered after it \[ is | was | will be \] inspected?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116258/it-will-be-delivered-after-it-is-was-will-be-inspected)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a mouthful of a sentence and not at all idiomatic.

We don't say: **After I will have done something...**

More likely in this context are:

> After finishing (my) lunch (by 2 p.m.), I'll go to the supermarket.
> and
> After I have finished (my) lunch (by 2 p.m.), I'll go to the supermarket.

To use your construction, you would have to say something like:

> I will have finished my lunch by 2 p.m., after which I'll go to the supermarket.